# Separate mailbox with Gmailify

Tags: gmail

I use [Gmailify](https://blog.google/products/gmail/gmailify-best-of-gmail-without-gmail/) to gather multiple sources into Gmail.

How can I separate those source? For the moment they are all thrown in the "Primary" tab.

Answer (score 2):

The settings for the import allow you to specify a label to apply to all incoming messages for that account. Just make a label for each of the different accounts. You can also tell it to skip the inbox if you don't want to see them in the main inbox label.